# Vuex Mutation does not work with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

New to vuex and nuxt so there may be a very simple fix to this. I have two middlewares, one makes an api call with AXIOS to github and the other pulls from a RSS feed of a medium.com user that convert to JSON.

The github mutation works fine when committing to store, the medium mutation does not commit to the store.

// store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    github: [],
    medium: [],
    blog: []
  })

  export const mutations = {
    ADD_MEDIUM(state, data) {
        data.items.forEach((el) => {
            state.medium.push({
                'createdOn': el.pubDate,
                'title': el.title,
                'url': el.link
            })
        })
    },
    ADD_GITHUB(state, data) {
        if(state.github.length === 0){
            data.data.forEach((el) => {
                state.github.push({
                    'createdOn': el.created_at,
                    'title': el.full_name,
                    'url': el.html_url
                  })
            })
        }
    },

  }
```

// middleware/medium.js

```
import rssParser from 'rss-parser'
let parser = new rssParser()

export default function ({ store, route }) {
    parser.parseURL('https://medium.com/feed/@user_name')
    .then((resp) => {
        store.commit('ADD_MEDIUM', resp)
    })

}
```

// middleware/github.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function ({ store, route }) {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/user_name/repos')
    .then((resp) => {
        store.commit('ADD_GITHUB', resp)
    })
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Errors?

Comment: The github mutation properly commits to the store, the medium mutation does not. Will update post for clarity

Comment: OK, but what *does* happen? Are you seeing the network request fire?
 Are you seeing it come back successfully?
 Have you `console.log`ged the value of `resp` to make sure it's what you expect?

Comment: I can console.log the response from Medium that has converted to JSON from inside the mutation function. It simply doesn't commit to store.

Comment: Next steps: `console.log` state and data within the mutation. Try pushing something static, like `state.medium.push({ foo: 'bar' })` for the mutation. etc.

Comment: It doesn't commit a static mutation either, it also doesn't show that the ADD_MEDIUM mutation was fired.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for future search. The rss-parser wasn't returning when it was fired because it lacked CORS.

```
import rssParser from 'rss-parser'
const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"

export default function ({ store, route }) {
    let parser = new rssParser()

    parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + 'https://medium.com/feed/@user_name', (err, feed) => {
        console.log(feed)
        store.commit('ADD_MEDIUM', feed)
    })
}
```

Comment: It wasn't spewing CORS errors into the browser's error log?

Comment: No, and even more odd was that it would console.log on first build without the CORS.